# get value from another column by using their alias

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code

```
select tblData.nama as namamhs,
       tblData.nilai as nilai_A,
       tblData1.nama,
       tblData1.nilai as nilai_B,
       case
          when(tblData.nilai-tblData1.nilai<0)
          then (tblData.nilai-tblData1.nilai)*-1
          when(tblData.nilai-tblData1.nilai>=0)
          then (tblData.nilai-tblData1.nilai)
       end as selisih
from tblData,tblData as tblData1
where tblData1.nama<>tblData.nama
order by tblData1.nama DESC;
```

my question is how to get the value from tblData.nilai by using their alias which is nilai_A ?

i tried

```
case
when(nilai_A-nilai_B<0)
```

but this error comes out

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 13 in file: 'well.sql': Unknown column 'nilai_A' in 'field list'
```

Comment: just write it longhand. It will be faster than the solution provided below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can query it like this if you want to use the alias

```
SELECT nilai_A,nilai_B,
CASE WHEN ((nilai_A - nilai_B)<0) then /*do something*/ ELSE /*do something*/ END AS new_Alias
FROM (
     your query /*except for the ORDER BY Clause*/
     )A
ORDER BY /*your column alias*/ DESC;
```

In this query you will use all the aliases you assigned on your original query.